# why am I having Xrm.Page.Data always equals null in javascript in CRM Web resource?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to use a web resource in Dynamics CRM 2011.
When using `Xrm.Page.Data`, I always have Data as null.

What can be missing or wrong here?

Comment: Please show some code. Where do you use the resource?

Comment: What kind of resource: html, silverlight, js?

Comment: Try `window.parent.Xrm.Page.data` from your webresource.

Answer (score 4):

1. Make sure you're waiting for the onload event to execute your script.  data will be null before this (detail forms).
2. I'm not sure it is available at all in grid views / other ribbon contexts.
3. It is `Xrm.Page.data` (data is all lower case).

Comment: The casing is key here I think (lower (data) as opposed to how it is written above (Data))